# choose people with identical name and family sql

Tags: sql, database

I need choose all people which have identical name and family from city lviv.
This is my db tables

```
depart
 debt   city
  43    odesa
  23    kiev
  79    lviv
  78    lviv

empl            
ide  fn ln  debt
341 ki  trt 43
354 jed vt  79
 43 ged gf  79
 73 ged gf  79
456 jkl gdfg    78
532 kkhg    vjv 23
 45 ki  vt  79
243 ki  vt  78
```

This is expected result

```
  fn    ln
 ged    gf
  ki    vt
```

I wrote such script

```
select distinct FN, LN from empl inner join depart on depart.DEBT=empl.DEBT
where LN  in 
(select
LN from empl 
 group by LN
having count(LN)>1)
and 
FN  in 
(select
FN from empl 
group by FN
having count(FN)>1)
and
depart.CITY='lviv';
```

But it doesn't choose identical records and displays record with ide 354. How modify it?
I use oracle with toad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select fn, ln
from 
    depart
         inner join 
    empl 
         on depart.debt = empl.debt
where 
    city = 'lviv'
group by fn, ln
having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT E.FN, E.LN 
FROM EMPL E LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPART D
ON E.DEBT=D.DEBT
WHERE CITY = 'LVIV'
GROUP BY E.FN, E.LN
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```